# sublime text 3 select lines after finding a specific word

Tags: sublimetext3

I have this text:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

I want in Sublime text 3, to select the lines that have "Lorem" without using the mouse.

Thank You, for the help.

Comment: Regex is the answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text were pasted in one line in Sublime Text so i manually moved each sentence into a single line. Then I used this regex:

```
^.*\b(Lorem)\b.*
```

In the search function, getting this result:

[image: Result]
*Click for fullsize*

Note that you will have to enable the Regular Expression in the bottom left corner.